# User Defined Function to VLookup into Closed Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to create a User Defined Function to `vlookup` into a closed workbook on my machine. The below function works while testing it in VBA, but I get the `#VALUE` error in Excel when attempting to use the function. Any ideas on this? I believe I may be able to use the VBA `Evaluate` function to help, but so far have had no luck.

```
Function CUSIP_Deal_Map(CUSIP As String, DataField As String) As Variant

Dim colIndex As Integer ' for vlookup
Dim invalidDataField As Boolean
invalidDataField = False

' Switch statement, to transform from a "DataField" into a column number to be used in VLookUp

Select Case DataField
   Case "Deal"
      colIndex = 2
   Case "Class"
      colIndex = 5
   Case "DealNum"
      colIndex = 6
   Case "Vintage"
      colIndex = 11
   Case "Pool"
      colIndex = 12
   Case "Index"
      colIndex = 13
   Case Else
      invalidDataField = True
   End Select

'Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\CUSIP_Map.xlsx") 'hard code location

Dim VLU_data As Variant
VLU_data = wbk.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CUSIP, Worksheets("CUSIP_Map").Range("A:M"), colIndex, False) 'vlookup data from "database"

Call wbk.Close(False) 'close connection

' Return data
If invalidDataField Then
    CUSIP_Deal_Map = "Invalid DataField"
Else
    CUSIP_Deal_Map = VLU_data
End If

End Function
```

The intended use in Excel would be to utilize a formula like `=CUSIP_Deal_Map("123ABC","Deal")`

I can test this in VBA, using this code, which returns the value I'm expecting:

```
Sub test()
MsgBox CUSIP_Deal_Map("123ABC", "Deal")
End Sub
```

Still, this doesn't work within Excel itself. I found a ["pull" UDF](http://numbermonger.com/2012/02/11/excel-pull-function-creating-dynamic-links-to-closed-workbooks/) online which seems to do something similar, but have been unsuccessful modifying it for my purposes.

Comment: Are those Select Case values the column header labels across row 1 of the closed **CUSIP_Map** worksheet?

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, these are the column headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because a *UDF()* call from within a Sub can open a file, but the same *UDF()* called from a worksheet cell cannot.

**EDIT#1:**

- insure the *UDF* is in a standard module.
- at the very top of the module include `Public wbk as Workbook`
- create a workbook Open event macro in your workbook code area to open the secondary workbook and initialize `wbk`

Comment: Is there some work-around though? For example, I've tried to modify this pull UDF (posted http://numbermonger.com/2012/02/11/excel-pull-function-creating-dynamic-links-to-closed-workbooks/) which is designed to access data from a closed workbook, but have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: I would open the workbook **outside of** the *UDF()*

Comment: Sorry, could you please post an example? I'm somewhat new to VBA.

Comment: "create a workbook Open event macro in your workbook code area to open the secondary workbook and initialize wbk" Is that not what I'm doing with the following code? 

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\CUSIP_Map.xlsx")

Comment: **YES!!**  but you must move that line of code from the *UDF()* to the *Event* macro!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78453/discussion-between-nsw-and-garys-student).

Answer (score 0):

OK, with the limitation already brokered by [Gary's Student](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student), you may want to rethink the idea of a UDF altogether. With those values from the Select Case statement in the first row of the closed **CUSIP_Map** worksheet, either of these standard worksheet formulas will do.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, 'C:\[CUSIP_Map.xlsx]CUSIP_Map'!$A:$M, MATCH("Vintage", 'C:\[CUSIP_Map.xlsx]CUSIP_Map'!$1:$1, 0), FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(A1, 'C:\[CUSIP_Map.xlsx]CUSIP_Map'!$A:$M, LOOKUP("Class", {"Class","Deal","DealNum","Index","Pool","Vintage"}, {5,2,6,13,12,11}), FALSE)
```

A1 would be value to look up in the CUSIP_Map's column A. Instead of a VBA select case, the column to return is determined by either a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) of the first row column headers or a hard-coded [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-df82ce98-edf9-46ea-8189-b0470e5e0e93) of text and column numbers. Note that the LOOKUP has its values in ascending order and that it may not have as much error control as the MATCH as it will attempt partial matches. An [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) as a wrapper can return "Invalid DataField" on MATCH errors.