# Is it possible to get specific data from another sheet using a created Function?

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to create an Excel function with this concept: based on user's inputed currency code, search for the code and get the correspondent exchange rate value from another workbook's sheet.

Example:

```
User input in cell: =xrate(220) '220 being the code for dollar
Function returns: 5.000 'dollar exchange rate present in second workbook
```

I have little to none knowledge in creating functions in VBA, but tried the following:

```
Function xrate(code as Long)

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook 'wb for the function
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\User\Test\rates.xlsm") 'wb with the rates
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Rates")

ws2.Activate

'Column B is where the code is at and Column F has the correspondent Exchange Rate
For i = 1 to 156 '156 being the last row with data
    
        If ws2.Cells(i,"B").Value = code then

            xrate = Cells(i,"F").Value

        End if

Next i

End Function
```

I've tested the same code as a "Sub" and it worked normally, but as a function it returns me #VALUE! error and seems to do nothing whatsoever.

The table with the rates cannot be in the same workbook that the function will be used because the table has to be updated daily and the users let their workbooks always locked by use.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: It will be better you create a sub to pull exchange rate from the workbook and place in a master list reference with a button, then you use your `UDF` to call the value from the master list within your workbook.

Comment: It is a relatively small table so I would fetch the entire rates table (using Data, Get Data, From Workbook) into a separate sheet on your current workbook and use a simple XLOOKUP (or VLOOKUP for older Excel versions) function to get the data from that new worksheet.

Comment: [Very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377817/user-defined-function-to-vlookup-into-closed-workbook). Also [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920206/excel-udf-to-reference-table-in-closed-workbook-for-lookup).